# Compile Kernel 3.10.107 for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, drivers, kernel-parameters

Is there a good way to compile and use kernel 3.10.107 on Ubuntu 16:04 LTS?

My main reason is that I have development/server machine where I want to add additional USB device what have drivers only for Kernel 3.10.107. My current kernel version is 4.10.0-30-generic.

Or is there a way to adapt that driver for new kernel?

Here is details about driver: https://github.com/FrescoLogic/FL2000

Comment: Follow this tuto : [How to Compile and Install Linux Kernel v4.9.11 Source On a Debian / Ubuntu Linux](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-building-installing-a-custom-linux-kernel/) just replace the kernel version v4.9.11 by v 3.10.107

Comment: @GAD3R TO follow all steps? Is there some guideline to not made some mistake? I don't want to broke current machine.

Comment: Wouldn't an older (3.x) kernel break some of the Ubuntu 16 programs? A lot changed between kernel 3.x and 4.x ... Perhaps an older distro in a virtual machine.

Comment: @jc__ I can't use virtual machine. I need 3 monthors on one machine. 2 is already connected on graphic card and 3th need to go with FL2000 USB display driver. I generaly want to adapt this plugin to work on bigger kernel version if is possible